# Chat system signaling server

Tags: android, ios, sockets

I'm building a mobile apps with chat system implementation , but I've some questions:

1. What is best signalling server for android & ios? I've used socket.io before but it only for javascript.
2. Should I store all user socket into database or not?
3. And is there any more efficient way to build a chat system without signalling server?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Socket.io` is not only for JavaScript. For example, take a look into the following library which supports both WebSocket and Socket.IO connections:

**Android**: https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync

**iOS**: http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/

However, between WebSockets and Socket.IO, I would recommend using WebSockets. It's a message oriented protocol where you simple use a `send()` call on sending side and the corresponding `receive()` is immediately invoked at the receiving end.

WebSockets seem to be the way to go, since there is very good support for them server-side, and client side ([Android](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync), [iOS](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket)).

Comment: Thank you! And i have another question, should i use websockets/socket.io for checking online user? i've some ideas that when any user logged into system, i will generate token for that user and store it in database! And if user logout, i will delete that user's token! Is it good or bad ideas?

Comment: yes you can use that approach. But why not simply change the user's status to "offline" or "online" when you detect a connect/disconnect? No need for a token.

Comment: But where i should store token, database or in the server? Because if store it on server, when server have any problems, all token will be lost?

Answer (score 0):

the best way for build a chat application like viber is use to protocol like xmpp.

you would using asmack for client side and openfire for server side.

by using this protocol could have offlineMessage , delivery message, user status,vcard,..